# How to configure two log4j for the application

Tags: java, log4j

I need to generate two log files for all the methods and classes in different layouts. is it possible?

Comment: Would two diffent appenders in the same log configuration do what you need?

Comment: try to use appender for logging

Comment: i am able to configure appenders in a Class inside Static function. but i want to do in the log4j properties file.

Comment: Please chech the example provided: [Log4j Multiple Appender Example](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/log4j/log4j-example-multiple-appender.html)

Answer (score 0):

#### log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=error, file1, file2, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.file1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.file1.File= file1.log
log4j.appender.file1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file1.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n <--- Different pattern 

log4j.appender.file2=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.file2.File= file2.log
log4j.appender.file2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file2.layout.ConversionPattern=%p (%F:%L) - %m%n <--- Different pattern
```

#### SimplestCode.java

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

public class SimplestCode {

    static final Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(in.mdtareque.log4j.test.SimplestCode.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PropertyConfigurator.configure("resources/log4j.properties");

        logger.warn("WARN");
        logger.error("ERROR");
        logger.fatal("FATAL");

    }
}
```

The logs files are created in project home directory for the above config.

#### file1.log

```
ERROR main in.mdtareque.log4j.test.SimplestCode - ERROR
FATAL main in.mdtareque.log4j.test.SimplestCode - FATAL
```

#### file2.log

```
ERROR (SimplestCode.java:18) - ERROR
FATAL (SimplestCode.java:19) - FATAL
```

[Check more documentation here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html)